# How to avoid "what goes up must come down" in motion equations

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, physics

I am simulating a slot machine spinning and would like to start with an initial velocity and gradually apply a negative acceleration until the total displacement has reached the desired slot. The issue I'm having is: unless I carefully tune the parameters (initial velocity), the slot spins past its target and then reverses direction and finally lands on the correct face.

I used the standard motion equation

```
displacement = initial_velocity*delta_time + 1/2*acceleration*delta_time^2
```

to derive the equation for acceleration

```
acceleration = (2*total_displacement - 2*initial_velocity*delta_time) / delta_time^2
```

Is there any equation which will tell me what acceleration to use if I want to land directly on the target without reversing? Is acceleration the right concept? I'd greatly appreciate any insights into this issue.

Comment: Achieve orbital velocity.  :-)

Comment: In electronic servos like elevator motors, a large reverse pulse is put on the motor just before it is to stop. This is to ensure it doesn't overshoot and have to back up like in your simulator. The reverse pulse needs time and magnitude adjustment but it might solve your problem. So forget initial velocity and rate of acceleration tuning. Just kick in the pulse whenever the wheel gets below a threshold speed.

Comment: I didn't mean you should not use deceleration. I just meant you might try adding the reverse kick near the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above equations are correct and shouldn't result in any backwards spinning if used correctly. I was simply running the simulation past the total duration described in the equation (`deltaTime`), which resulted in a reversal of the velocity direction.

See @Saranga B great answer for even more accurate equations to model a spinning slot, using rotation-based physics.

Answer (score 1):

How much deceleration $a$ to apply depends on the initial velocity $v$. Let D be the displacement, then the correct amount to apply is

$$a = \frac{v^2}{2D}$$

which can be derived from the two equations below,

$$D = vt - \frac{1}{2}at^2$$
$$v=at$$

by eliminating $t$.

Comment: Is the duration of the spin not a dependent variable here? Plugging this in results in an acceleration in the range of 1000, about 6 orders of magnitude greater than expected..

Comment: This is the equation for $a$ assuming full stop at distance $D$ with initial velocity $v$. No $\Delta t$ needed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess its better to think about this problem in terms of angular velocity ($\omega$) and acceleration ($\alpha$). The slot machine stops due to friction, therefore there is constant angular deceleration. You should find the angular velocity that would require to turn the slot machine to a desired target.

$\theta_f$ = $\theta_i + \omega t + \frac{1}{2}\alpha t^2$

So if there are $n$ targets on the rotating dial, then they are $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ radians apart. That is $\theta_f - \theta_i = \frac{2\pi}{n}$. Rearrange the equation to find the desired $\omega$. Hope this helps.